# Problem in calling class from tomcat in JNI

Tags: java, visual-c++, java-native-interface

I am getting a problem. I am calling a Java class from VC++. When I run a Java program from ID it works fine but when I deploy it on tomcat it gives me an exception and when I started debugging it I found that it returns null in `cls`. How can I give an absolute path in FindClass so that it can also be called from tomcat? This class also resides in jar file.

```
JNIEnv *envx = NULL;

JavaVM * vm = NULL;

env1->GetJavaVM(&vm);

int status = vm->AttachCurrentThread((void **)&envx,NULL);

jclass cls = envx->FindClass("/org/software/initmethod/GetInitValue");

jmethodID mid = envx->GetStaticMethodID(cls,"onRegStateChanged","(II)I");

if(mid==NULL)
{
    return 0;
}

printf("In C\n");

envx->CallStaticIntMethod(cls,mid,s1,s2);

vm->DetachCurrentThread();

return 0;
```

Comment: Copy code and exception, please.

Comment: I have pasted the code. and the exception is "Access Violation Code" and when i debugged it the class returns null becasue it cannot find the class in tomcat.

Answer (score 3):

Tomcat uses different classloaders for each application, so it can keep them isolate. That is, if you have a web application that provide a Consumer class (as a Person) and other web application that provides the same classname Consumer (as a Thread) it it can cause conflict and problem for both applications (which Consumer should Tomcat load?). To answer that tomcat create a ClassLoader for each applicaton with the their own isolated jars and classes. As we can see in the diagram below, this is the hierachy of Tomcat ClassLoaders. The problem is that your JNI call is getting the System ClassLoader (Default) which does not have information of the class that you're trying to invoke.

```
      Bootstrap
          |
       System
          |
       Common
      /      \
 Catalina   Shared
             /   \
        Webapp1  Webapp2 ...
```

To resolve this you need to find your application classloader. You can do this easily by calling `getClass().getClassLoader()` in some class that you defined in your application. This will get the ClassLoader that loaded that class, which we know that is your Web Application ClassLoader. After that you call the `loadClass("foo.bar.ClassThatIWant"`) method and get the desired class. In Java everything would look like this:

```
ClassLoader cl = AWebClass.class.getClassLoader();
Class myClass = cl.loadClass("foo.bar.ClassThatIWant");
```

Do do the trick in JNI you do the following, suppose that you have passed your Web Application Class Loader as a parameter called `webCL`.

```
jclass classLoaderClass = env->GetObjectClass(webCL);
jmethodID loadClassMethod = env->GetMethodID(classLoaderClass, "loadClass", "(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Class;");

const char *className = "foo.bar.ClassThatIWant"; // This needs dots because it's the arg for Java
jstring javaClassName = env->NewStringUTF(desiredClass);

jclass desiredClass = env->CallObjectMethod(webCL, loadClassMethod, javaClassName);
```